# .NET Core Identity Login Page handler OnGetAync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I working on a .NET Core 3.1 project using Identity. On the `Login.cs.html` page, the `OnGetAsync()` page handler is as follows:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
    }

    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync())
        .ToList();

    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
}
```

I'm a bit confused about the line of code `returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");` and why it is written this way. Why is it checking if `returnUrl` is `null`, won't it always be `null`? Why not remove the `string returnUrl = null` as a method parameter and assign `ReturnUrl = Url.Content("~/");`? Am I missing some thing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `returnUrl` parameter has been set up to use an [optional argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments):

> If no argument is sent for that parameter, the default value is used.

With the default setup for Identity, the value for `returnUrl` comes from the query-string of the request URL. For example, the following URL provides a value for the `returnUrl` argument:

```
/Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl=/Some/Protected/Route
```

In this case, `returnUrl` will *not* be `null`. However, consider the following URL:

```
/Identity/Account/Login
```

In this case, `returnUrl` will be `null`. There's no URL to redirect to after the login process completes, so the line you've called out will set it to `Url.Content("~/")`. That just means it'll end up redirecting the user to the root of the web application, which is typically the home page.